# How to spread div which is inside content to wider than its content?

Tags: jquery-mobile, datagrid

Ex. Code below is represented as Blue Box, I want to expand 2 grid to Yellow one. But, the problem is; This .. need to be inside `content` but it always have margin left and right. I don't know how to solve this.

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="d" >
        <div class="ui-grid-a" >
            <div class="ui-block-a"><strong>Time:</strong></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" id="price-order-timestamp">yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss</div>
        </div>

        <div style="width:100%;"> <!-- Here-->
            <div class="ui-grid-d" id="data-table-header" >
                <div class="ui-block-a">Label A</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">Label B</div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">Label C</div>
                <div class="ui-block-d">Label D</div>
                <div class="ui-block-e">Label E</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-d" id="data-table" >
                <div class="ui-block-a">A</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">B</div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">C</div>
                <div class="ui-block-d">D</div>
                <div class="ui-block-e">E</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the default padding added to the `data-role=content` tag, add the following override in your custom.css

```
#myPageId .ui-content{
    padding-left:0;
    padding​-right:0;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/LW5aC/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. by the way, I don't want to change default .ui-content because there are some that need default content. Is it possible to create custom content like .ui-content-custom{..} ? I'm new to Js. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just override for this particular page by specifying pageId in the css selector. Updated code sample in answer.